# Visual Studio 2012: “Apply Code Changes” is disabled C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Recently converted our projects over to 2012 from 2010 (winapi/desktop/c++/32bit).

And now the "Apply Code Changes" button seems to remain disabled.  Similarly, when I make a change to the source I'm currently debugging, my breakpoints go white (meaning not enabled due to source mismatch).

I've not changed the project settings explicitly, but I have verified that this is a debug build, that "incremental linking" is enabled.

There is a setting I'm unfamiliar with  that is blank "create hot patchable image", but I'm not sure if that is related to debug edit & continue or not (the MSDN for it is unclear, whereas the incremental linking is quite clear that it is required.  [UPDATE: this has nothing to do with it]

Anyone know what is required in 2012 to fully enable edit & continue in 2012 for C++ (NOT managed - ordinary C++)?

---

Some extra info:  Desktop GUI .exe target, statically linked to MFC and CRT.  Unicode.  All libraries double-checked for debug, incremental linking, and program database for edit & continue.

Comment: You could start with a clean 2012 project where edit & continue is working, and one by one change all settings to match your project. Unless someone already figured it out, soon we will know.

Comment: I didn't recall that one needed to enable E&C at the Tools|Options level for VS2012 as a whole.  I recalled only needing to enable it at the project level.  So, now I feel an idiot! ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting over by deleting everything in the Debug folder and all generated files, do a "Build/Clean Solution" and "Rebuild All."

EDIT: As a last resort, try reading the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esaeyddf.aspx Try/Tools/Options/Debugging/Edit and Continue/Ask Me First

---

Quick Answer:
+ Tools
++ Options
+++ Debugging
++++ Edit and Continue
+++++ Native-only options
++++++ Enable native Edit and Continue **<- Set this**

Comment: @Mordachai I cheated. I read the documentation. See the answer now. Maybe that will work.

Comment: My assumptions made an ass of me, this time.  I assumed that the overall edit & continue would be configured "on".  Wrong.  Installing VS 2012 on a machine with 2010 ignored that setting, and instead gave me "edit & continue" enabled, but "native-only options" (which is the only system it applies to) to "off".  !@#$
Thanks for the "RTFM" :D

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem , here is my method : 
Project-> XXXX(project name) Properties, go to C/C++ -> general , check the debug information format , the right one should be :Program Database for Edit And Continue (/ZI)